# Mosfet Switching Energy

Tags: mosfet, switching, energy, power-dissipation

How can I calculate the energy required to switch a Mosfet knowing the peak power, and the drain to source capacitance?

Comment: Don't you mean the gate to source capacitance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total gate charge curve is what you're looking for:

(From [here.](https://www.rohm.com/electronics-basics/transistors/total-gate-charge))

[image]

Look on the vertical axis for the voltage you are driving the gate to.  That will give you the charge necessary to switch the FET on to the desired Vgs. Now voltage is the amount of energy (J) per unit charge (C), so that gives you the energy required for every switching event.